# Create an react component with input using only ES3

Tags: reactjs, input, google-apps-script

I'm using google script it my daily practice and recenlty tried to connect react.js to client side of web-app. 
I've achived to connect react.js using require.js, but the point is that I not able to use jsx. I have to use vanila javascript, to create and render components.

```
requirejs.config({
    // module name mapped to CDN url
    paths: {
        // Require.js appends `.js` extension for you
        'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react',
        'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom'
    }
});

requirejs(['react', 'react-dom'], function(React, ReactDOM) {
  var app, cr, r_comp, el, app;
  cr = React.createElement;
  r_comp = new React.Component();
  el = [];
   el[0] = React.createElement('button', {
        type: 'submit',
        className: 'postfix',
        disabled: false
    }, 'Automate');
   el[1] = React.createElement('input', { placeholder: 'Enter a url', type: 'url', autoFocus: true }, 'default_url')

   app = document.getElementById('app');
   ReactDOM.render(el[1], app);

});
```

when I'm trying to create first element(el[0]) it works fine, and a button appears
[image]
but when I'm trying to create second element - input, it respones with error

> "react.js:20145 Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must
>   neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`."

[image]
googling that error I didn't found any usefull information for this case, or I don't understand react is well enough to understand what should I change to overcome the error.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want `default_url` to be input name

```
el[1] = React.createElement('input', {
  placeholder: 'Enter a url',
  type: 'url', autoFocus: true,
  name: 'default_url'
}
/*, no children*/);
```

Comment: Oh, man! That works! It is really simple if you know the stuff.